# Selenium - How to provide values to this grid ? all the text field DOM's are similar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, ui-automation

[image]

Above is my text field i need provide values to the grid.

Below is the DOM.

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0016" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1638429953954-0-uiGrid-0016-cell"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope"></div></div>
  
  
  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0017" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1638429953954-0-uiGrid-0017-cell"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope"></div></div>
```

For all the text field only unique element is class but class is dynamically changing to some values. can someone help me on this.

Addind some more DOM

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0025" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1638429953955-0-uiGrid-0025-cell"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope"></div></div>
  
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope" xpath="1"></div>
  <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-0045" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1638429953957-0-uiGrid-0045-cell"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope"></div></div>
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope" xpath="1"></div>
```

Comment: Use XPath/CSS indices.

Comment: How ? which element we need to take ?

Comment: Which one is your text field where you are putting values? Can you share some more from the DOM?

Comment: Please share full HTML of that table